# Can't Login to Debian 7.7 with Kerberos/NIS user

Tags: debian, pam, kerberos, nis

I have a Debian 7.7 system I am trying to configure to use Kerberos and NIS, both served from an Active Directory server.

I have kerberos set up such that I can `kinit` a set of credentials from the AD server.

I have NIS set up such that I can `su - $USER` to an AD user and everything works.

I just can't log in as the user.

When I log in through the console, I get these logs in the auth.log:

```
Nov  5 10:22:41 debian login[3888]: pam_krb5(login:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry
Nov  5 10:22:45 debian login[3888]: pam_krb5(login:auth): (user dmackintosh) attempting authentication as dmackintosh@AD.$ZONE
Nov  5 10:22:45 debian login[3888]: pam_krb5(login:auth): user dmackintosh authenticated as dmackintosh@AD.$ZONE
Nov  5 10:22:45 debian login[3888]: pam_krb5(login:auth): (user dmackintosh) temporarily storing credentials in /tmp/krb5cc_pam_54ruC8
Nov  5 10:22:45 debian login[3888]: pam_krb5(login:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (success)
Nov  5 10:22:45 debian login[3888]: Authentication failure
```

When I log in through ssh, I get:

```
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: entry (nonull)
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): (user dmackintosh) attempting authentication as dmackintosh@AD.$ZONE
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): user dmackintosh authenticated as dmackintosh@AD.$ZONE
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): (user dmackintosh) temporarily storing credentials in /tmp/krb5cc_pam_NQ9vhz
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: pam_krb5(sshd:auth): pam_sm_authenticate: exit (success)
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: Failed password for dmackintosh from 10.8.0.21 port 47234 ssh2
Nov  5 10:24:00 debian sshd[7641]: fatal: Access denied for user dmackintosh by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

In both cases, the login attempt is immediately kicked out.  I know the password is correct because A) it passes the kinit test and B) if I deliberately type the wrong password, I get a your-password-is-wrong wait before the password is prompted for again.

The configuration of PAM is pretty much stock as per /usr/share/doc/libpam-krb5/README.Debian.  Only PAM debugging statements have been added.

SSH has been changed to enable the GSSAPIAuthentication and GSSAPICleanupCredentials options, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I have this working with CentOS 5 and 6, so it has to be a configuration problem on the debian system somewhere.

I know that the internet wants me to do this with LDAP rather than NIS, but I have to keep NIS around for "reasons".

**Update**: I have discovered that if there is an entry in /etc/shadow for the user, it works.  This totally defeats the purpose of using NIS, but anyways.  This leads me to believe it is a problem with my /etc/nsswitch.conf file, which looks as so:

```
passwd:         files nis
group:          files nis
shadow:         files nis

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis

automount:      nis
```

**Update2:** I have discovered that without the extra information in /etc/shadow, `getent shadow` does not return the NIS shadow information which is visible from `ypcat shadow`.  I have also discovered that Gentoo and Ubuntu are similarly affected; RH-family distros do not seem to be, even though RH-family systems don't return the contents of the shadow NIS map through `getent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to enable the `broken_shadow` functionality for the pam_unix.

In `/etc/pam.d/common-account`, find the pam_unix line and add `broken_shadow` to the end of it:

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so  broken_shadow
```

Description:

> Some network setups include 'x' in a crypted password field, but have
>   no shadow information. When this happens, pam_unix fails account
>   management because it can't read this information. A 'brokenshadow'
>   option assumes that errors reading the information mean that it
>   doesn't exist, and allows the user to log in.